# How to execute powershell script that online every offline disk using nodejs

Tags: node.js, powershell

Writing the following directly in the powershell will online every offline disk found in the system

```
Get-Disk | Where-Object IsOffline –Eq $True | Set-Disk –IsOffline $False
```

However, the problem Is when I try to make it to a script as onlinedisktest.ps1 I will get the following error message.

```
Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'False'.
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\project-main\new\scripts\onlinedisktest.ps1:1 char:12
+ Get-Disk | Where-Object IsOffline â€“Eq $True | Set-Disk â€“IsOffline ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

My code

```
static async run(executable, args, opts = {}) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const child = spawn(executable, args, {
                shell: true,
                stdio: ["pipe", process.stdout, process.stderr],
                ...opts,
            });
            child.on("error", reject);
            child.on("exit", (code) => {
                if (code === 0) {
                    resolve(code);
                } else {
                    const e = new Error('Process exited with error code ' + code);
                    e.code = code;
                    reject(e);
                }
            });
        });
}
      
static async exeOnlineDisk () {

        try {
            const code = await this.run('powershell', ["-executionpolicy", "unrestricted", "-file", __dirname + "\\scripts\\onlinedisktest.ps1"]);
            if (code == 0) {
                //success
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            process.exit(e.code || 1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Your error seems to be related to an encoding issue, as you can see in the error message, the hyphen `-` seems to be converted to `â€“` which is why `Where-Object` could be throwing that error.

Comment: I find it weird that it works writing directly into the powershell terminal but not when executing the onlinedisktest.ps1. When I .\onlinedisktest.ps1 and try to execute the script directly from powershell I get the same error.

Comment: Is the encoding of your script `UTF-8 with BOM`?

Comment: I am not sure, how do I check/change it? All I have in my onlinedisktest.ps1 is ```Get-Disk | Where-Object IsOffline –Eq $True | Set-Disk –IsOffline $False``` my other ps1 script works fine with ```set-disk 2 -ErrorAction Stop -IsOffline $false```

Comment: Wish I could help you but Encoding is not something I understand well enough to give you a proper answer. Hopefully someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: You helped me to get on the right track with the encoding, I solved it by making a new txt file and saved it as UTF-8 encoding. Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help and glad you could solve your problem. I was gonna propose just saving a new file but didn't want to give inaccurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the encoding of your file. Try saving the script you're calling as UTF 8.

[image]

Comment: ```Get-Disk | where-object -property "OperationalStatus" -eq Offline | Set-Disk –IsOffline $False``` gives error ```At C:\Users\me\Desktop\project-main\new\scripts\onlinedisktest.ps1:1 char:80
+ ... operty "OperationalStatus" -eq Offline | Set-Disk â€“IsOffline $False
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString```

Comment: What do you mean by _`where-object` does not understand the switch `IsOffline`_??? `IsOffline` is a valid property of the object returned by `Get-Disk` and `Where-Object` __can__ filter by this property.